# How do I call .get() on a 2d ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a 2d ArrayList

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

I want to get the item at say (0,0).

I'm looking for something like:

```
list.get(0,0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You must use

```
list.get(0).get(0)
```

since you are not using a real 2-dimensional `List` but a `List` of `Lists`.

Answer (score 6):

Java doesn't have 2d lists (or arrays, for that matter). Use something like this:

```
list.get(0).get(0)
```

Note that arrays have a similar issue. You do not do this:

```
array[0,0]  // WRONG! This isn't Fortran!
```

Instead you do this:

```
array[0][0]
```

Answer (score 5):

As follows

```
String value = list.get(0).get(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a program to traverse the 2D-ArrayList. In this program instead of **LineX** your can get item in the list (i , j ) **:-)**

*PROGRAM:*

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
int no_of_rows = scan.nextInt();         //Number of rows 
int no_of_columns = scan.nextInt();      //Number of columns 
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < no_of_rows; i++) {      
    list.add(new ArrayList<>());      //For every instance of row create an Arraylist
    for (int j = 0; j < no_of_columns; j++) {
        list.get(i).add(scan.next());        //Specify values for each indices
    }
}
//ArrayList Travesal
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i).get(j)+" ");   //LineX
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

*OUTPUT:*

```
2 3 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

It being List of List, you try :

```
String val = list.get(0).get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use below syntex to fullfill our requirement:
arrIJ=arr.get(i).get(j);

I have to find the diagonal difference for the 2D list, where I use the above syntax:

Code of Diagonal Difference in list:

```
public static int diagonalDifference(**List<List<Integer>> arr**) {
        int size=arr.size();
        int forwardDiagonal=0;
        int backwardDiagonal=0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                if(i==j){
                    forwardDiagonal=forwardDiagonal+**arr.get(i).get(j)**;
                }
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=size-1;i>=0;i--){
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                if(i+j==size-1){
                    backwardDiagonal=backwardDiagonal+**arr.get(i).get(j)**;
                }
            }
        }
        return Math.abs(forwardDiagonal-backwardDiagonal);

    }
```